# How do I apply a dark theme to Visual Studio 2015 IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How should I apply a dark theme to Visual Studio 2015 IDE. Is it a setting I could turn on? There used to be a VS settings file in the previous version like 2008 and 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools->Options->Environment->General->Color theme: Dark

Answer (score 0):

```
Tools->Options->Environment->Color theme
```